# How can I populate fields of a JSON schema in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, schema, populate

I'm trying to populate a JSON object, so I can sent it to a REST endpoint and get a response.

There's no API to "build" these requests, so I'm just storing a JSON text file that looks like this:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "range": {
          "request_time": {
            "gte": {{START_TIME}},
            "lte": {{END_TIME}},
            "format": "epoch_millis"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter": [
      {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
          "{{LOCATION_FIELD_NAME}}": {
            "top_left": {
              "lat": {{TOP_LEFT_LAT}},
              "lon": {{TOP_LEFT_LON}}
            },
            "bottom_right": {
              "lat": {{BOTTOM_RIGHT_LAT}},
              "lon": {{BOTTOM_RIGHT_LON}}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "should": [],
    "must_not": []
  }
}
```

Then I'm populating a HashMap with key, value pairs where the keys are `{{*EXPRESSION*}}` and the values are the `Strings`, `Doubles`, etc. that I wish to replace them with.

Finally, I go through the text file searching for the delimiters: `{{`, `}}`, and replace the keys with the values.

This seems really ghetto to me, and it's obviously hard to test. I'm using the Jackson library to parse my responses, and it's great that the `ObjectMapper` lets you convert JSON to POJO and back, but I don't want to go through the hassle of defining 15 classes just to compile the above skeleton (which I know will be the same every time). Is there a de-facto way of providing Jackson with a JSON schema via text file, and populating only certain fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Manually writting json can be fine for small things, but it can become a hassle, more so if you start having characters that need to be escaped, date's, etc. The easiest way I find to do this is working with google's gson library.

Comment: how about replacing expressions in a json string using java String APIs and then forming an object (one single object) from updated string?

Comment: One approach would be to parse the template to a `JsonNode` with `mapper.readTree`, then walk the tree to update your templated values. It would be more robust because you could be sure that your serialised value was valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does have an API for manipulating JSON trees. You can use it to read your template from a file or string and then update only the parts you need to.

Use `readTree` to parse your template:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectNode template = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(
    "{\n" +
    "  \"query\": {\n" +
    "    \"bool\": {\n" +
    "      \"must\": [],\n" +
    "      \"filter\": [{\"match_all\": {}}],\n" +
    "      \"should\": [],\n" +
    "      \"must_not\": []\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "  }\n" +
    "}");
```

Then locate the node you want to update with a JSON Pointer:

```
ArrayNode must = (ArrayNode) template.at("/query/bool/must");
```

And update it:

```
must
    .addObject()
    .with("range")
    .with("request_time")
    .put("gte", "2018-01-14T00:00:00.000Z")
    .put("lte", "2018-01-13T00:00:00.000Z")
    .put("format", "epoch_millis");
```

You can even mix it with the object mapping API:

```
ArrayNode filter = (ArrayNode) template.at("/query/bool/filter");
filter.addObject()
    .with("geo_bounding_box")
    .putPOJO(
        "custom_location",
        new GeoBoundingBox(
            new LatLon(-36.854307, 174.771923),
            new LatLon(-36.861172, 174.780636)
        )
    );
```

Serialisation of trees is performed the same way as with objects:

```
mapper
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .withoutFeatures(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET)
    .writeValue(System.out, template);
```